# Netbeans Author Tag?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 11, and when I create a new Javadoc tag, my default name appears in the form of:

```
/**
@author Sarah <GENERIC_EMAIL_HERE>
**/
public class X {}
```

How can I change these default values? I recall opening a file a long time ago, but I have long since forgotten how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, in previous versions, all you had to do was:

Steps:

1. Go to Tools > Templates.
2. Click on Settings button.
3. On template settings, un-comment the last line and change the value of "user" to what you want to be shown after the @author tag.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I would recommend being careful about your grammar though.